# GCC section attribute and preprocessing

Tags: gcc

Can you tell me what type of macro this is? What does it do?

```
#define PER_CPU_ALIGNED_SECTION "..shared_aligned"

#define PER_CPU_BASE_SECTION ".data..percpu"

    #define __PCPU_ATTRS(sec)       
    __percpu __attribute__((section(PER_CPU_BASE_SECTION sec))) 
    PER_CPU_ATTRIBUTES
```

What is the dot operator in the first two macros?

Can you tell me more about the "section" attribute used in GCC? I couldn't find much info on the Web about this. Can you give me a link about this?

Thanks.

Comment: You did read about gcc section attribute, did't you? I think the docs are pretty clear. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Comment: What are the double dots for?

Comment: It's just a section name; standard sections have a dot in their name (ex: .bss) hence they are probably following this naming convention. Several OSes actually enforce a naming scheme (ex: OS X .segment,section). These custom sections are only useful if the linker is instructed how to handle them; in gnu toolchain a linkerscript is used. It's a text file referring to sections by names and providing handling instructions.